# Mapping JSON to DTO from Akka Stream

Tags: java, design-patterns, akka

Using the below code I run a flow named `requestFlow` which maps JSON to a Java DTO.

The class `StreamManager` gathers the sources and runs the flows from method `runStreams`.
Class `StreamLauncher` starts `StreamManager`.`runStreams`

Class `TestStream` tests `requestFlow`.

StreamFlowsTest tests the flows contained in StreamFlows

I’ve used the Lombok builder annotation in StreamFlows :

```
@Builder
@ToString
public class StreamFlows {
```

I’ve not seen a Lombok builder used in the Akka docs but I think it is a good pattern to follow. Is there any reason not to use it in this case?

Overall is this a good design for mapping JSON to DTO using Akka Streams, is there a design pattern I could follow?

src :

```
package qs.q4;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;

import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@Jacksonized
public class RequestDto {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss")
    private final Date datePurchased;

    private String someOtherField;

}


package qs.q4;

import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.ToString;

@Builder
@ToString
public class StreamFlows {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public final Flow<String, RequestDto, NotUsed> requestFlow = Flow.of(String.class)
            .map(input -> mapper.readValue(input, RequestDto.class))
            .log("error");
}

package qs.q4;

import akka.Done;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Behaviors;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class StreamLauncher {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(Behaviors.empty(), "actorSystem");
        final Sink<RequestDto, CompletionStage<Done>> printSink = Sink.foreach(System.out::println);

        StreamManager.runStreams(printSink , actorSystem);

    }

}

package qs.q4;

import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.Graph;
import akka.stream.SinkShape;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Merge;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import java.util.Collections;

public class StreamManager {

    private static final Source<String, NotUsed> getDataSource1(){
        final String json1 = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-02-03 21:32:017\"}";
        final String json2 = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-02-03 21:32:017\"},{\"unknownField\":\"test\"}";

        final Source<String, NotUsed> source1 = Source.repeat(json1).take(3);
        final Source<String, NotUsed> source2 = Source.repeat(json2).take(3);
        final Source<String, NotUsed> source3 = Source.repeat(json2).take(3);

        return Source.combine(source1, source2, Collections.singletonList(source3), Merge::create);
    }

    private static final Source<String, NotUsed> getDataSource2(){
        final String json1 = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-03-03 21:32:017\"}";
        final String json2 = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-02-03 21:32:017\"},{\"unknownField\":\"test\"}";

        final Source<String, NotUsed> source1 = Source.repeat(json1).take(3);
        final Source<String, NotUsed> source2 = Source.repeat(json2).take(5);
        final Source<String, NotUsed> source3 = Source.repeat(json2).take(13);

        return Source.combine(source1, source2, Collections.singletonList(source3), Merge::create);
    }

    public static void runStreams(final Graph<SinkShape<RequestDto>, ?> sink, final ActorSystem actorSystem){
        getDataSource1().via(StreamFlows.builder().build().requestFlow).to(sink).run(actorSystem);
        getDataSource2().via(StreamFlows.builder().build().requestFlow).to(sink).run(actorSystem);
    }
}


package qs.q4;

import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;
import akka.testkit.javadsl.TestKit;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestStream {

    static ActorSystem system;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        system = ActorSystem.create("StreamTestKitDocTest");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tear_down() {
        TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
        system = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_stream_flow() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        final int STREAM_SIZE = 3;
        final TestKit probe = new TestKit(system);

        final Date datePurchasedDate = new Date(1643923937000L);
        final String json1 = "{\"datePurchased\":\"2022-02-03 21:32:017\"}";
        final Source<String, NotUsed> source = Source.repeat(json1).take(STREAM_SIZE);

        final Flow<String, RequestDto, NotUsed> flowUnderTest = StreamFlows.builder().build().requestFlow;
        final CompletionStage<List<RequestDto>> result = source.via(flowUnderTest).runWith(Sink.seq(), system);
        final List<RequestDto> requestDtoList = result.toCompletableFuture().get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertEquals(STREAM_SIZE, requestDtoList.size());
        assertEquals(datePurchasedDate, requestDtoList.get(0).getDatePurchased());
        assertEquals(datePurchasedDate, requestDtoList.get(1).getDatePurchased());
        assertEquals(datePurchasedDate, requestDtoList.get(2).getDatePurchased());
    }

}
```

Comment: With the proviso that StackOverflow isn't a code review site: I doubt there's a problem with that usage of Lombok (as it's basically a Java equivalent for some of the `case class` machinery in Scala, which works really well with Akka).  As far as the stream approach, if it works and meets your needs, go for it.

Comment: @LeviRamsey ok thanks, maybe I should migrate to code review stackexchange if the question is leaning toward code review .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to code review site by a moderator.

Comment: Fundamentally any deserialization part of a stream (if it has a flow shape: 1 inlet, 1 outlet) is going to be a `Flow<String, DTO, NotUsed>`.  About the only extra thing you might do is to not make deserialization failure stop the stream: making the output an `Optional` or something that can wrap failure or success (a `Try` or `Either` in Scala encodes that: I don't know Java equivalents) would accomplish this, as would having a fan-out (1 inlet, 2 outlets) where failures get sent to a different flow (doing that may or may not fit your usecase well).